# How would I juxtapose between the unity of God (Shema) in Deuteronomy 6.4 and the concept of Trinity in the Old Testament

Tags: nature-of-god, trinity, deuteronomy, monotheism

"Hear, O Israel: The LORD our God, the LORD is one!

Comment: What do you mean by "juxtapose"? Do you really want to hold them in tension? Or do you want to know how Trinitarians can say that they are monotheists?

Comment: This question needs additional scripture to indicate that there *is* the concept of Trinity in the Old Testament. Without that, the question appears to be based on speculation.

Answer (score 4):

The Jews of Old Testament times, and even to this day, had no concept of a Trinity--as the Shema indicates.  It is well established that Jews have always been monotheists, including during the time of Christ.

Jesus, in addressing the woman at the well, who was a Samaritan, spoke, as a Jew, of this Jewish belief in God.

John 4:21-24

> <sup>**21**</sup> Jesus saith unto her, Woman, believe me, the hour cometh, when ye shall neither in this mountain, nor yet at Jerusalem, worship the Father. <sup>**22**</sup> Ye worship ye know not what: **we know what we worship**: for salvation is of the Jews. <sup>**23**</sup> But the hour cometh, and now is, when **the true worshippers shall worship the Father** in spirit and in truth: for the Father seeketh such to worship him.

Jesus' message is clear; he taught worship of "the Father," not of a Trinity.

Comment: David spoke, saying, 'The Lord said unto my Lord . . . . ' Abraham saw three men approach and he said, 'My Lord'. God's chosen people (and they are not all Israel, who are of Israel) have ever known God for whom he is. They know by revelation and they know by faith. Jehovah looked down, and the Angel was in the bush and Elohim spoke out of the bush. These things are plain to see. And God said' Let us make man in our own image'.

Comment: @nigelJ YHWH said unto my lord.... Prophetic indeed.  YHWH is 1.  Who is YHWH speaking to?

Answer (score 3):

##### Assuming Unitarianism

Only when assuming Unitarianism, the Shema and the Trinity would be in conflict. The LORD is one, one what? one person? one being? You can indeed see fuzzy pictures of the Trinity in the Old Testament throughout various passages, but of course, the triune nature of God is revealed to us in the New Testament, let's let how Paul explained the Shema for us.

##### Paul's explanation of the Shema

1 Corinthians 8:6 (NASB95)

> yet for us there is but one God, the Father, from whom are all things and we exist for Him; and one Lord, Jesus Christ, by whom are all things, and we exist through Him.

- One God (1 Corinthians 8:6) = our God (Deuteronomy 6:4)
- One Lord (1 Corinthians 8:6) = The LORD (Deuteronomy 6:4)

Paul explained the Shema for us, he used the same keywords, One, God, Lord, but he actually expanded it for us so we can understand what and who God is.

###### Why should we compare Deuteronomy 6:4 with 1 Corinthians 8:6 when the first one was written in Hebrew and the other was written in Greek? and how do we deal with the Tetragrammaton (YHWH) being translated into Greek?

When the apostles quoted from the Old Testament in their gospels and epistles, they quoted from the Greek Septuagint also known as the LXX (the Greek translation of the Old Testament), because the people they were talking to (such as the Corinthians in this case) didn't speak Hebrew and used the Greek Septuagint as their Old Testament bible, that's how you can use Deuteronomy 6:4 in the LXX as a reference to 1 Corinthians 8:6. In regard to the Tetragrammaton (YHWH), in the LXX, it's simply rendered as Κύριος (Kyrios), simply as "Lord" in English, which is the same title that is used for our Lord Jesus Christ throughout the whole New Testament and in 1 Corinthians 8:6.

Comment: The Lord in 1 Corinthians 8:6 is not YHWH. It is Jesus. Jesus has a God John 17:3. His Father/God does not pray to Jesus.  “the construction of theophoric names, starting with the letters “Jeho” is evidence that God’s name is actually ‘Jehovah’ (and that Christ’s name is actually Jehoshua)” – Smith’s 1863“A Dictionary of the Bible”
 Section 2.1 Jesus is not  YHWH/God, Acts 3:13 The God of Abraham, and of Isaac, and of Jacob, the God of our fathers, hath glorified his Servant Jesus; whom ye delivered up, and denied before the face of Pilate, when he had determined to release him.

Comment: *the triune nature of God is revealed to us in the New Testament* is derived from reading the Bible eisegetically and creates innumerable contradictions.  Let’s stick to the facts presented by God’s anointed authors and reject the others.

Comment: @AlexBalilo You see, Trinitarians never disagree with the passages that you bring up against the deity of Christ, because we accept them, but we don't just accept certain parts of the bible, we accept the whole bible (Tota Scriptura). Does Jesus have a God? yes he does, why? because he humbled himself in position and became a man but does not affect his deity in any shape or form, read Phil 2:5-11, is Jesus God the Father's servant? yes indeed for the same reason and it was prophesied in Isa 53, that was the role of the Messiah the eternal Son of God, to serve and fulfill his Father's purpose.

Comment: @AlexBalilo On the other hand, anti-Trinitarians run away and are afraid of passages such as John 1:1-18, John 12:36-41 in parallel to Isaiah 6 where Jesus is clearly identified as the Jehovah of hosts that Isaiah saw in his vision in Isaiah 6, or even John 17 that anti-Trinitarians abuse, ignoring John 17:5 where Jesus requests the Father to glorify him with the glory which he had with him before the world was, or even other passages where Jesus is identified as the CREATOR, how can you ignore those? Unfortunately, you don't accept the whole bible, only parts of it that you like.

Comment: @steveowen Actually, the Trinity is the result of a proper exegesis of God's word not eisegesis, it is anti-trinitarians that cherry pick and only accept certain parts of God's word and completely ignore others that show the deity of our Lord Jesus. Trinitarians accept all of God's word, not just certain parts, that is why Christians hold firm to Sola Scriptura and Tota Scriptura.

Comment: @Isha. The verses that you cited does not express a multi person god idea. You can always post a question about verses you think supports your assertion if you want to.

Comment: @ isha Yes, that’s why Jesus sits *next* to God, and still has the same God - precisely because he is not that God. *Only* the Father knows the son and *only* the son knows the Father. And you think we ignore bits! Best wishes for your journey out of contradiction. If you believe the Gospels you will not be able to align your expressed interpretations without inventing another Jesus. One with two natures etc, who is simultaneously mortal and immortal.